# How to remove the "Powered by BluSpice" icon in the footer of my MediaWiki site?

Tags: mediawiki, footer, bluespice

On my MediaWiki site I have in de footer 2 "powered by" icons. One for "MediaWiki" and one for "BlueSpice". I like to remove them.

The MediaWiki icon is easy to remove with:
`unset ($wgFooterIcons['poweredby']);`

I tried `unset ($wgFooterIcons['poweredby']['bluespice']);` to remove the BlueSpice, but it doesn't work anymore.

Who knows the secret code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned it off with this line:

```
$wgFooterIcons['poweredby']['bluespice'] = false;
```

Comment: Thanks! That is the trick for BlueSpice. But how toe remove also MediaWiki? It should be "unset( $wgFooterIcons['poweredby'] );" but than returns bluespice.

Comment: To remove the Powered by Mediawiki icon can with "unset ($wgFooterIcons['poweredby']['mediawiki']);"